# Login and Register System VisualBasic

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I trying to create a login and register system in WindowsForms VB.NET, but i dont know how to start that... I beginner in programming and i use this site to get some help to my questions. But i dont find any answer to my question!
Can someone give-me a hand pls?
How to save the user input??
OBS: I'am newbie at programming, just training with this to use in future project.

...

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    If TextBox1.Text = Nothing Then

        MsgBox("Enter a valid username", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation)

        If TextBox2.Text = Nothing Then

            MsgBox("Enter a valid password!", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation)

            If TextBox3.Text = Nothing Then

                MsgBox("Enter a valid email", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation)

            End If

        End If

    End If


    If TextBox1.Text = "admin" Or TextBox1.Text = "Admin" Then

        MsgBox("You can't register as Admin!", MsgBoxStyle.Critical)

    End If

    If (TextBox2.TextLength < 5) Then

        MsgBox("Password need to be more than 5 characters", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation)

    End If

End Sub

Private Sub TextBox2_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox2.TextChanged

    TextBox2.PasswordChar = "*"

End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: There's not really anything special about user management. It is simply data access like any other. To register, you gather data from the user and insert it into the database, just like for any other data. To login you gather data from the user and query the database with it, just like for any other data. Finding a match means a successful login. You should approach this problem like any other, i.e. break it up into parts and address each part individually. If you want to start with the registration then you need to be able to insert data to a database. Can you do that? If not, go learn how.

Comment: I see a youtube vídeo and he show's that:

My.Settings.Username = TextBox1.text                                                                          My Settings.Password = TextBox2.text
My.Settings.Email = TextBox3.text
My.Settings.Save()

MsgBox("Sucess!", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "REGISTER")

Comment: You probably ought to do a bit more research than a single YouTube video. If you only want to store a single user name and password in your user settings then you can do that but a proper user management system is going to involve multiple sets of credentials stored in a database. Either way, the fact that it is user management doesn't make it special. It's still just a mater of getting data from the user and either putting it somewhere or comparing it to existing data. Plan your app before writing code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you planning to store the user's information in a database? If so, you can start off by learning how to connect to a local/online database. Passwords should always use a good encryption method with no decryption method in code. In addition, never name a database column 'password' or anything relating to a password.

There's a lot more to logins when you're wanting to store them somewhere. Learn the basics of databases and go from there. It will be fun and worth your time! :)